What would cause species only distantly related and with vast morphological differences to still be able to interbreed?
In my books' universe, there are twelve sapient races, counting humans. They are all descended from a single species that was effectively identical to modern humans, but they have each adapted to the environment of a different planet and have become humanoids with some of the features of animals. The types of animals are across the board, from every major classification (one avian, one amphibian, several mammalian, two reptilian with one having fishlike traits, and one insectoid, although that last one is still a vertebrate).
Here's the problem. All of these species are supposed to be able to interbreed and have viable offspring, but their body plans have significant differences. For example, Ornithiforms, Drachenheul and Suileans have wings (separate from their arms), and thus six limbs as opposed to everyone else's four. Salamandrion, Argonites, Drachenheul and Sunekites have digitigrade lower limbs as opposed to plantigrade, as all the others have. Vulpines and Ailurids have ears set in a completely different place on their heads than the others, who have ear placement like humans'. Some have fur, some have feathers, and some have scales, all in varying degrees of coverage over the body.
The fact that hybrids are possible is a plot point in the story itself I can't let go of without messing up other parts of my writing and was intentionally written in to distinguish my story from my inspirations, so I'd much rather keep it.
Thus my question is: Are there any real life equivalents or genetic loopholes I can exploit to explain why these vastly different creatures are still able to hybridize? Or am I forced to just "handwave" it in?

I do have some parameters I've already figured out:
-The only pairing in which I've actually ironed out exactly what'll happen is ordinary human/any other creature. That will usually end up as one or the other without any real problems. Your mom is a human and your dad is a Vulpine? You'll most likely either look entirely human or entirely Vulpine, and they'd have to genetically screen you to pick up on your hybrid ancestry. There are a few exceptions, but this is the standard.
-These hybrids are typically fertile, but will usually only pass on one of their parent race's traits to their offspring. If you want a whole city of Argonite-Ailurid hybrids for whatever reason, you'll have to get a bunch of Ailurids and Argonites to marry each other, and the hybrids in turn have a chance of producing more. You can't just start with one Ail/Ar hybrid, get them with a member of one of their parent type, and expect their children to be just like them. The hybrid appearance disappears after a generation or two.
-Gestational period, the size of the offspring at birth, and growth rate are all similar across the races, so there's no real problem there.
-They all have XY sex determination, are dimorphic in the same way humans are, and are all able to suckle their young.

Your species and civilization (from other posts) are already impossible without Sufficiently Advanced Technology. You can solve all your problems with the same Sufficiently Advanced Technology. Nanomachines, son.

Would the scientific reasons even matter? Will you devote a chapter about interbreeding of dogs to justify it? Would a reader care? You've already got 'fantasy' humanoids. You have a litany of games, movies and written media where interbreeding is possible to support a readers suspension of disbelief. All you need to do is use it. "Because they can" is perfectly acceptable.

@Trioxidane yes, but as a writer I like having these situations ironed out. Plus, the people I’ve shared this work with are predominantly other writers who might pick up on these kinds of things.

Everybody in your books being wrong in their beliefs about them being only very distantly related, that would do it.. your protagonists are all mind bogglingly ignorant and dumb, or perhaps are ideologically captured by a religious cult that tells them what to believe, and it's completely wrong.

@Trioxidane is right. We get a bit frustrated with questions asking us to crowbar science into impossible situations. Science is, in many ways, the enemy of worldbuilding because it's ruthless and inflexible. The simple truth is, science doesn't have all the answers. As AlexP points out, most discoveries of this type are through luck. You're digging for details that have a far higher chance of stopping your worldbuilding than they ever will to improve it. Good worldbuilding is as much knowing when to stop crawling through the rabbit hole as it is to start.

You may want to consider a scenario à la Busby: the 12 different sibling species are actually a haploid stage in the (very complex) reproductive cycle of a single ancestor super-species. When the sibling species mate in special circumstances, the offspring is not the usual hybrid with 23 pairs of chromosoms: it is a specimen of the ancestor, hermaphrodite species, with a double complement of 2x23 pairs of chromosomes.

The "super-foetus" obtained by inaugurating the pregnancy with the fusion of 2 false-twin zygotes in the womb of the mother into a single "double-zygote" cell. To ensure an hermaphrodite offspring, the 2 ovules were pre-programmed to only fuse with a sperm cell of a given persuasion, X for one and Y for the other, so that the twin zygotes have different sexes. See Busby's "The end of the Line", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F._M._Busby#Demu

@JBH  I suppose you're right. I do have a tendency to go down rabbit holes. I apologize if my repeated questions about one specific storyline are starting to become annoying and take up room better questions could've occupied.

Might you be viewing evolution the wrong way round?
I suggest you're query really seems to be, 'why…' while evolution says 'why not?'

Biology is messy.
Most usually, very closely related but different species cannot interbreed. For example, humans cannot interbreed with chimpanzees, although the two species finally separated completely only about 4 million years ago.
But most usually does not mean always. In quite a few cases all or almost all of the species in a genus can interbreed. For example, almost or maybe even all the species in the genus Canis, dogs, wolves, jackals, coyotes, can and do interbreed.
It even happens that sometimes even distantly related species can interbreed. Among vertebrates, the record is held by the Mississippi paddlefish (Polyodon spathula) and the Danube sturgeon (Acipenser gueldenstaedtii), two species of fish in two different families of the order Acipenseriformes; their most recent common ancestor species lived in the Jurassic period, 184 million years ago: but in 2019, a team of Hungarian researchers who were trying to see whether the two endangered species could be bred in captivity accidentally used paddlefish sperm instead of sturgeon sperm to fertilize sturgeon eggs, and very very much to their surprise they obtained viable offspring.
Among plants, interspecific hybridization is rampant; the reproductive systems of plants and animals are fundamentally different, and plants are quite ready to breed with different species. Intergeneric hybrids are also quite common. For example, the common wheat Triticum aestivum is an allohexaploid, with ancestors in three different species belonging to two different genera. Interfamilial hybrids are much rarer, but more numerous than among animals.
In plants it is also relatively easy to perform somatic hybridization, where cells from two different species are artificially fused. The best know somatic hybrid is triticale, a hybrid of the common wheat and rye, combining the yield potential and grain quality of wheat with the disease and environmental tolerance of rye; it is somewhat successful commercially, with a worldwide production of about 14 million tons.

Even amongst just dogs, the Chihuahua-Great Dane breed is always amusing to contemplate.

Do you have any sources that Homo Sapiens and Chimpanzee cannot interbreed? As i understand it we are chemically capable to have fertalisation hapen, but all the experiments destroy the embrio once it reaches about 100 cells for ethical reasons.

We don't have the same number of chromosomes as Chimps, which would make fertile offspring mechanically difficult (supposedly impossible for mammals).

@v010dya: The great Russian and Soviet biologist Ilya Ivanov tried but failed. The only recent experiments I am aware of are oriented towards the production of human-animal chimeras resulting from the merger of two embryos, which is, in my opinion, outside of what most people would call interbreeding.

@T.E.D.: Horses (with 64 chromosomes) and donkeys (with 62) routinely interbreed, and there are rare but verified instances when resulting mules were fertile.

@AlexP - I'd think "usually infertile" would not constitute fully "interbreeding" . Perhaps OP feels that's good enough though? Its their question.

This "sturdlefish" as the article called it is actually very close to what I've been imagining. My creatures are more distant appearance-wise, but genetically are likely closer than those two fish. This is exactly the kind of information I needed, actually.

"For example, humans cannot interbreed with chimpanzees" This is not known to be true. "We don't have the same number of chromosomes as Chimps, which would make fertile offspring mechanically difficult" Difficult, but not necessarily incompatible enough that they couldn't interbreed and produce fertile offspring. Fertile female mules, and their offspring, have been documented.

@ouflak: We know that the gene flow between the human lineage and the chimp lineage stopped some 4 million years ago. For most of this time, the two lineages lived side by side in Africa. If interbreeding was possible, there would have been some gene flow between them during the almost 4 million years of cohabitation; but there wasn't. (What is even more interesting is that the two lineages began to diverge about 8 million years ago, but gene flow continued for about 4 million years. Then something happened which put a stop to it.)

"there would have been some gene flow between them during the almost 4 million years of cohabitation" I don't know how you could make such a speculative statement without a thorough understanding of the environment and conditions underwhich gene flow stopped. The stoppage of gene flow among species is process that has occurred many times throughout evolutionary history. Genetic drift, or lack thereof, afterwords may occur for all kinds of reasons - not entirely understood. 'Cohabitation' for you might mean something completely different to those creatures living 4 million years ago.

This is simple... if you start with the premise that all of these variants on the theme of human were genetically engineered from base humans and were designed to be able to interbreed.
If these races have a basic human genome, plus extra chromosomes that encode all of the racially-specific traits, those chromosomes could also be designed so that if they find themselves in the presence of different racial chromosomes, certain traits can co-exist with or inactivate certain other racial traits.
As author, all you need do is decide what traits would reasonably be able to co-exist in a hybrid, and say that the genetic engineers who set all this up designed the system so that those traits that can co-exist do coexist... and that those that can't coexist... just don't, with the less useful trait being suppressed.
As for crosses between genetically-engineered human-successor morphs and unaltered humans, it is certainly possible for a single genetically engineered chromosome to be able to detect if it is present as a single chromosome in the resultant offspring at the single-cell stage and to duplicate itself to be diploid, so that a cross between a human and a genegineered race will always result in a member of the genegineered race... unless the geneticists didn't want that to happen, in which case, the single extra chromosome could effectively self-destruct, resulting in offspring that was always human.  Again, author's choice.

The extra chromosome(s) for each race concept actually makes a lot of sense to explain why human/whatever else hybrids are usually either all human or all the other kind. I can't believe I didn't think of that.

At some point in the story's past, there was one species.
At the story's present, there are several.
How did you get from one to the other?
I am going to assume that the story's past is our present and the story's present is our future.  This might not be the case, adjust the advice as needed.
If you are expecting natural evolution to turn humans into a flying species, you are going to sorely disappointed.  Even on a planet with very low gravity, the difference is simply too great.
Breathing water like a fish is even worse. Not going to happen.
So, genetic engineering to the rescue.  At some point we will have genetic engineers who know our genome inside and out and can makes offspring species do whatever they want.
This knowledge may be lost at your story's present, or it might still be around.  Your choice.
When the new species are all interfertile, this is because they were designed to be so.
I don't know, you don't know, and your readers don't know enough about the subject to really understand how that was done, because NOBODY knows yet.  You had better NOT try any explanation beyond "The Ancestors made it so".
Some points though: Everybody need to be basically mammals with cosmetic changes. Basic cell chemistry must be the same.  Blood must carry oxygen and other chemicals around.
Eggs and sperm must work the we know it and even pregnancy must be basically the same.  Some variation might be acceptable, but too much difference between mother and child will kill at least the child.
Even with the Ancestor Genetic Engineers doing their best, I suspect there will be problems with some combinations.

Yes, they are all effectively the same blood, chemistry, and reproductive-wise. While the exist in something of an alternate universe to ours (and thus there's no "our time" to them), there has been sufficient time for advanced technology like genetic engineering to be discovered, so that could be a possiblity.

Remember that what goes on in the worldbuilding is Much more than what the reader will see. It's ok if you don't have all of the details ironed out, but it is sometimes necessary for you as a write to know exactly how something works, even if the readers Never see.
I'm writing a somewhat similar story where humans left earth and moved to a bunch of different planets in another solar system. I have one flying group of humans and one fish-like group of people for example.
After doing a bunch of looking into evolution, I determined it wasn't feasible to have them naturally evolved into these different species, so genetic engineering was the best way to go. It would likely help you to do the same.
One thing you could do is have some hybrids work better than others. 2 mammalians breeding would produce healthier offspring than a birdlike and a fishlike couple. If a fish and a bird person reproduced, they might have offspring with either underdeveloped scales or feathers. That offspring may have a shorter life expectancy, disabilities, or be infertile. Of course, there could also be a slight chance that the offspring comes out healthy and matching One of the parents almost exactly, but realistically that would be an extremely rare scenario.
If you want to avoid that, you can go the non-natural way and have the vastly different species couples have to go to a lab or a clinic and essentially use technology to choose which of the species features it would have.

Thank you! Your point on 2 mammalians having more workable offspring as opposed to a birdlike and fishlike couple makes a lot of sense. I think in terms of genetic distance, my most distant couple would have to be my Arcturan (bearlike)/Ornithiform (birdlike) pairing. That might get interesting.

In humans, upwards of 90% of our DNA is completely inactive. A lot of variation in species' appearance is already a matter of what genes are turned on, so if I were to approach this issue I would say that all of these races actually have the exact same DNA, but depending on the parents certain genes are turned on or off. If the Y chromosome, for example, just had a little key part in it that told the DNA being read to turn on or off certain genes that would drastically alter the physical appearance.
That said, I don't see why this sort of thing would naturally evolve, it might not allow for a child of two species to really hybridize without maybe having issues, and and it might not be able to cause some of the really drastic physiological differences. It would have to be artifically engineered to make sense. I'm also not an expert at all and would suggest further research if this is the solution you want to go with.
Biggest thing I think would not make sense here is the number of limbs, those differentiate really early and don't really change. The only way I can see it working is if all of the species actually had 6 limbs and the majority of them just vestigialize early on. Even so, it feels like a bit of a stretch that something that definitive of appearance would be neatly divided into a couple of little genetic packages that turned on or off at will.
